# Thinking Sphinx : Error : While Indexing. It says column ambigous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, mysql-error-1052

indexing index 'users_core'...
ERROR: index 'users_core': sql_range_query: Column 'searchable' in where clause is ambiguous (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:3306/myname).

cant i use the searchable keyword . is it reserved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you join multiple tables, and more than one column is named searchable?

Comment: I have different table named projects which also has a column named searchable . but how come it cause problem here. i am trying to index users table.

Comment: It makes a difference if you join the users table with the other table and they both have a column named `searchable`. If that's the case, then you'd need to classify which column you want to select, i.e. `users.searchable`

Comment: But i wonder why that namespace problem happens .
we dont need to specify the table name if we are dealing only with one table rt ?  
"select * from users" = "select users.* from users".  
Is sphinx combining the conditions and building a unique query for
indexing ?